# how to turn speaker on/off programmatically in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, speaker

I play a file through media player and I want to give options like speaker on/off, play though headset, bluetooth ,etc.
I tried the below code which works well for android 2.2 but I want something that can also work for 2.2 and 4.0 both.
Can you help me to programmatically turn the speaker on/off and playing via headphones?

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(isOn){
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);    
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
    }else{
        //Seems that this back and forth somehow resets the audio channel
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);     
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);        
    }
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(isOn);
```

P.S: I have given this permission in manifest:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

Comment: How you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 27):

Something like this might work on some devices (I've only tested in on an XPeria P):

```
final static int FOR_MEDIA = 1;
final static int FORCE_NONE = 0;
final static int FORCE_SPEAKER = 1;

Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
setForceUse.invoke(null, FOR_MEDIA, FORCE_SPEAKER);
// To get back to the default behaviour, use the combination FOR_MEDIA,FORCE_NONE.
```

The combination `FOR_MEDIA, FORCE_SPEAKER` is typically only used internally to route the FM-radio audio to the loudspeaker (since the FM-radio requires you to have a wired headset / headphone plugged in to act as an antenna). Devices that don't have FM-radio functionality (or uses an alternative implementation) might ignore this combination of parameters, so this method would not work on such a device.

Comment: This works on my Galaxy S2 and android 4.0.4. How did you come up with this idea? This is like a miracle

Comment: `setForceUse` is the method used internally to force certain audio types to a given device. The reason I know that is that I work with Android audio for a living.

Comment: I dislike hacks like this because they are almost certain to be broken by a future release of the Android framework. But this is the only way I have found that actually allows output via the speaker when the headset is plugged in. Works on a Huawei Y300 running Android-4.1.1

Comment: Hey Michael, when we have to set back the default behaviour, that is, let it play through earpeice, do we do  setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 0); ?

Comment: Its not working in Android Pie device, any idea why?

Comment: How can I force a webview to play audio via earpiece?

Answer (score 6):

```
AudioManager mAudioMgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 

Button mVolumeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Volume);
        mVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mAudioMgr.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
                    mAudioMgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    mAudioMgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
                    mAudioMgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    mAudioMgr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SpeakerPhone On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    mAudioMgr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
                    mAudioMgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                    mAudioMgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wired Headset On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can acquire either a rear speaker or a front earpiece at time.

If no accessory connected;

Use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` to use front speaker/earpiece. But this would play audio in earpiece not on speaker. To use rear speaker, use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`

If accessory connected; Use audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); & audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); to use front speaker/earpiece. But this would play audio in earpiece not on speaker. To use rear speaker, use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`

Note: Make sure `audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(boolean on)` and `audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(boolean on)` set to **`false`** to route audio via earpiece . And set either to **`true`** to route audio accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

try follow code snippet:

```
//for speakerphone on
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

//for headphone on
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

BTW,I tested in Android 7.0(Redmi 4x) and it worked fine.

Comment: This works for me! Yay! Had been struggling with this for a while. My only issue now is that there is about a second of dead air in the transition from speakerphone to receiver. Not a huge deal but a little annoying.

Comment: audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); this line code works for me

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. For all of you who are still searching for the answer. Well this is not a bug , but just a tricky thing . You need to use the PhoneStateListener

Using this guide : http://danielthat.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/android-make-phone-call-with-speaker-on.html

Answer (score 2):

if u just want to open your speakerphone on u just write this line in oncreate() of your activity.

```
static AudioManager audioManager =  (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
AudioManager audioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (isOn) {
        isOn = false;
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

    } else {
        isOn = true;
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    }
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(isOn);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
AudioManager.speakerphone(true);
```

Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Comment: I guess you mean `AudioManager.setSpeakerPhoneOn`? (which is what he's already using). There's no speakerphone method in AudioSystem.

Comment: Look at the link i posted . In that link you can find that method.

Comment: You wrote AudioSystem in your answer, but linked to the AudioManager reference. That's why I asked.

Comment: @chirag : AudioManager.speakerphone(true); This doesn't work.
Could you suggest something else which works both for 2.2 and 4.0

Comment: You must also do:
   
    `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);`

Comment: With call managers and that type of stuff, you have to implement a check to see if it is android 11+ or below that. Two seperate ways of doing things. Keep that in mind. The same goes for when bringing your activity to the front, so code as if it is two different OS's because in some way it is.