# Android - Getting audio to play through speakers

Tags: android, audio

I would like to play a mp3 audio file with the same speaker and volume when an user receive a phone call. 
I am using the following code

```
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

with the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

in the manifest

but it does not work. the volume is very high.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that call to `setSpeakerPhoneOn` (most likely) will do is to route both the music and the voice call to the loudspeaker, in which case they might be mixed together and the music may be downsampled to the voice call sample rate (8 or 16 kHz).

One thing you could try is what I proposed in [how to turn speaker on/off programatically in android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036221/how-to-turn-speaker-on-off-programatically-in-android-4-0)
This could let you let you route only the music to the loudspeaker while voice call audio is routed to the earpiece. It's not guaranteed to work on all devices though.

Comment: I am writing an audio guide for a museum. The content of the audio guide is saved on a mp3 file. I want that the play of this audio file is the same volume of a phone call so that the user have to move the phone near the ear. I have not play any music

Comment: Ok, so there's no actual voice call involved here. It sounds to me like what you actually want is to route the music to the earpiece. In that case you could try getting rid of your call to setSpeakerPhoneOn and instead call setAudioStreamType on your MediaPlayer object with the stream type set to STREAM_VOICE_CALL. That should route the audio from that MediaPlayer to the same device that a voice call would be routed to.