# How to play sound in Loud speaker even if the headphones are connected in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing an application which uses Headphone `Media Button` to get `LatLng` inputs. I initialized a `Media Player` whenever the button is pressed. Buzzer is playing. No problem with that. But the sound is playing via headphones only. I want to play those sounds in `Loud Speaker`. In order to notify input has been inserted to DB. I don't know how to play sound in Loud speaker even the Headphones are connected. Is there any way to complete this task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to turn speaker on/off programatically in android 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036221/how-to-turn-speaker-on-off-programatically-in-android-4-0)