# Change the audio routing from built-in speakers to loudspeakers in Android

Tags: android, audio

I want to play an audio file let's say from the loudspeakers and by the use of a button change it to built-in loudspeakers and vice versa. A built-in loudspeaker could be a headset, a bluetooth device. But let's consider for simplicity the built-in loudspeakers.

I'm doing the following thing:

1. Initialise the player with appropriate context and uri and then

   asyncPlayer.play(context, uri, true, st);

where st I have seen it takes the values STREAM_VOICE_CALL, STREAM_MUSIC, STREAM_RING, STREAM_NOTIFICATION

I have noticed that when I use the

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true/false);
```

This works only when the st value is STREAM_VOICE_CALL. For STREAM_RING I could do the same only my changing the mode, i.e.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

To be honest I find it a little bit counter-intuitive as I would expect that with any file I would be able to set the Speakerphone on and off without changing the mode...

Could you give me some indications on how it works, or any other suggestions?

The reason I'm using the asyncPlayer is because I want to do at the same time other things as well.

Thanks

Comment: `setSpeakerphoneOn`, as the name implies, should be used for toggling speaker phone mode on/off. It's not intended as a mechanism for changing the routing of arbitrary streams (e.g. music streams).

Comment: Yes...but if I have for instance STREAM_RING then why it doesn't change the speaker phone mode on/off?

Comment: What I would like to have is a mechanism in which I could turn the speaker phone mode on/off for any sound I play

Comment: Well, again, it's set**Speakerphone**On, not setLoudspeakerOn. The purpose of the function is if you've got a voice call and want to switch between the default call routing and using the loudspeaker + farfield mic. That's really the only use-case the function is intended for.

Comment: There are some hackish ways for re-routing music streams. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036221/how-to-turn-speaker-on-off-programatically-in-android-4-0/12037719#12037719  But I'm not aware anything that's officially supported. Things might've changed since I stopped working with audio-related Android stuff though.