# Turn on mobile earpiece forcefully

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

Following is the scenario:

- Headphones with mic are connected to a mobile device.

What i want to achieve programmatically:

- After a call is been initiated, audio from 3.5mm jack should (forcefully) be routed to mobile earpiece rather then headphone speakers, while the mic should be used of the headphones.

I have searched a lot on google but found methods only to forcefully turn on mobile external speakers.
Reference : [how to turn speaker on/off programmatically in android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036221/how-to-turn-speaker-on-off-programmatically-in-android-4-0)

While, my goal is to turn on earpiece forcefully.

My research from google:

- To achieve this there might be possibilities of system (root) permissions, which a third party application might need.
- You may have to write a modified audio driver from sources ? As the functionality is based on the operating system.

If it is possible, can any one guide me on this ?

**UPDATE**

One more reference: [Android - Getting audio to play through earpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece)

But the above code does not work on all phones.