# How to switch audio output programmatically in android 10 or up?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-audiomanager, speaker

I have an Android app in which I want to set the media output to a specific device, in my case the phone's internal speakers, while being connected to a bluetooth device. For clarity, I don't want only my app to play through a specific output. I want the system media output to change.

Yes I saw: [how to switch audio output programatically in android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859938/how-to-switch-audio-output-programatically-in-android-10). But using this method does not work.

What I am trying is using the audio manager to set the internal speaker for media:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(AudioService);
am.Mode = Mode.Normal;
am.StopBluetoothSco();
am.BluetoothScoOn = false;
am.SpeakerphoneOn = true;
```

In the manifest I have also put

When the code runs which is confirmed by the log in Visual studio it just doesn't work. In the media panel my bluetooth device is still selected. I also checked if it maybe did route the audio while not showing it, but it did just play on the bluetooth device.

Am I doing something wrong or is this even possible?
Or do I have to use something completely different?

If useful my device is a Samsung A41 with Android 11.
Using Visual studio Xamarin Android.