# How to switch audio output programmatically in android 13?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a simple android app that is able to switch current selected audio output device, system wide(similar to how you can do in windows in the taskbar widget).

based on the docs, the method [setCommunicationDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)) should replace the deprecated [setSpeakerphoneOn](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)) method from API 34 and above. however, no matter what I try I'm unable to switch my audio(music) output to other devices programmatically. also, it is noted that `setCommunicationDevice`

> should be used for communication use cases, for instance voice or video calls.

so, should I switch audio output for music? I'm after this for days, and the docs are lacking information, I'm feeling dumb.

also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587121/how-to-switch-audio-output-programmatically-in-android-10-or-up) that also asks the same but no answers (and the example there does not work either).

So my current goal is: assuming the music is played from a connected Bluetooth device, change the output to local built-in speaker when the user clicks on a button.

```kotlin
Button(
    onClick = {
      // failed attempts 
    }
) {
    Text("Set Phone speaker")
}
```

### fail 1 - setCommunicationDevice

```kotlin
val speakerDevice =
    audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
        .find { it.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER }
if (speakerDevice != null) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(speakerDevice)
        if (!result) {
            // result=true is true but the switch never occurs 
        }
    }
}
```

### fail 2 - setRouting

```kotlin
audioManager.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL, AudioManager.ROUTE_SPEAKER, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);
```

also, never works.

### fail 3 - setSpeakerphoneOn

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981179/10577976):

```
audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL;
audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

again, does not work.

I'm tasting again Google Pixel 7 phone android 13.

So, How can i switch audio output device, system wide, for any (Normal) audio output from the device?