# Working with two audio devices on android simultaneously

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming

Is it possible to work with both internal audio device (internal mic, and speaker), and external audio device (headset) simultaneously? I need to stream the audio between these two devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify exactly what you're trying to achieve in more detail. How does the microphone come in to play here?

As for playing a stream in the internal loudspeaker and a wired headset (i.e. regular 3.5mm stereo plug) at the same time, that should be possible on most handsets. That happens to be the typical behaviour for ringtone playback when you've got a wired headset attached, so using `STREAM_RING` *should* give you that routing.

Routing one sound to the loudspeaker and another sound to the wired headset is a different story. It is possible to do on some platforms (see my answer for [simultaneously using a headphone and speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker/14211450#14211450)) but there's no way of doing this in a way that is guaranteed to work on all (or even most) platforms, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I need to route the sound from mic to the output of the headset and the sound of mic headset to the output of the device (speaker). In another words I need to stream audio between internal and external audio devices. We need that because we use some custom made device instead of a headset (but it is enumerated in Android as a standard headset), and we need to stream the audio from mic/speaker to and from this device.

Comment: You want `headset mic -> loudspeaker` _and_ `internal mic -> headset` at the same time? Unfortunately that's unlikely to work, because many phones have a limit of one active input stream at the audio HAL level, which means that you can't record from two different input devices simultaneously (a common exception to this limitation is FM-Radio recording, but that's not exposed to 3rd party developers). Even if you did manage to record from two mics at the same time you'd still have the problem of outputting them to different output devices, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: It looks like I am able to output two different streams to both headphones and native speaker. I created two threads, each output to `STREAM_RING` or `STREAM_MUSIC` - and that works. But you may be right about recording from two devices - for now I had no luck with that. I was able to read data from internal mic, even if headphones are connected (by reading from `VOICE_DOWNLINK`) - but when I try to read both streams (from `VOICE_DOWNLINK` and from `MIC`) - it works only with one. I continue my investigations. Please let me know if you have any ideas. And thanks for help!