# Play sound both on the device speaker and headset at the same time

Tags: android, media-player

I am using `MediaPlayer` class to play sound. But there is an issue in my code. If headset is connected is connected to my device and then it play sound on headset, not on device speaker.

So my question is how to play sound both in device speaker and headset, if headset is still connected to the device.

**Code used to play sound**

```
m_MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SettingsAlarmToneActivity.this, R.raw.tone1);
m_MediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I think you can't because audio shouldn't go by speaker if headset is plugged in.

Comment: Then how the caller tone ring in device speaker if the headset is plugged in.

Comment: It is android build-in, I think you will need root access.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Could u tell me how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to play the same sound in both devices, or different sounds? In the first case, use the `RING` or `ALARM` stream type for your player. In the second, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker/14211450#14211450

Comment: In my case i playing the same sound in both.

Comment: Then it should be sufficient to set one of the stream types I mentioned using `setAudioStreamType`. You'll probably have to use a different way of constructing your `MediaPlayer` object, because `create` calls `prepare` internally, and `setAudioStreamType` has to be called before `prepare`.

Comment: @Michael Can u show me with an example...I am not able to get what need to do.

Comment: I don't have an example, but I'm sure you can find some if you google for it. Or just follow [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: @Michael No suceess yet.. i tried using this line of code  m_MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SettingsAlarmToneActivity.this, R.raw.tone1);
    m_MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaRouter` is Androids way to route audio signals to different devices, like internal speaker, headphone or Bluetooth speakers.

You'll need to run on API Level 16 or above (Android 4.1+). Here's, what the [developers page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html) says:

> Media router. The new APIs MediaRouter, MediaRouteActionProvider, and MediaRouteButton provide standard mechanisms and UI for choosing where to play media.

To be honest, I haven't seen any example, where two actual devices were fired with an Audio signal, only that two MediaPlayer can now gapless play after each other.