# Different audio streams to headphone jack and hands free speaker Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm doing two way FSK modulation/demodulation through the jack plug and want to use the phone speaker for audio feedback at the same time (not the fsk stream but some other sound for notifications).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks...

Comment: Please add a sample code what you have already done and exactly what problem you have.

Comment: If you mean simultaneously, then in general I'd say no. But it is possible to do on _some_ devices (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker/14211450#14211450).