# Has anyone tried to play sounds through the speakers and headphones at the same time? Android + iOS

Tags: android, ios, audio, speaker, headphones

I currently have an app that generates sounds on the fly, like pure tones and white noise, and I can hear that on the headphones.
Is it possible to send the same signal to the internal speakers and the headphones at the same time? I would like to do this on iOS 7 and KitKat. Probably, Android L and iOS 8 in the future...

On iOS I have seen that a new feature was introduced on iOS 6, multiroute, which let select the audio route. The thing is that when I connect the headphones I can not choose the internal speakers. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I think that would help me on Android...

On Android, I have found this [simultaneously using a headphone and speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker). But that is from one year ago.

Has anyone tried this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, I don't think you can route audio to both the headphones and the speakers. You can control the routing to different audio interfaces using the multi-route audio code included in this [Apple WWDC slideshow](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_505__audio_session_and_multiroute_audio_in_ios.pdf), but the built-in headphone jack and speakers are part of the same audio interface, and I don't think there is a way to override the behavior within that interface of disabling the speaker when the headphones are connected.

Answer (score 0):

To do this on Android, it should suffice to set your audio stream to STREAM_ALARM:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
//
// Your player initialisation code here
//
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```