# How to play sound when headphone connected in android programatically?

Tags: android

I am working on one of the project which need to play sound simultaneously when headphone is connected.

I am using below code but no luck

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [simultaneously using a headphone and speaker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to handle the action sent when the headset is plugged. You need after that to check if the action sent by the broadcast equals Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG in the onReceive method, then you can play your sound using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            //Headset is unplugged
            break;
        case 1:
            //Headset is plugged
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);   
            mediaPlayer.start();
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
        }
    }
}
```

Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610712/2354845

Comment: Thank you but I have to play sound on both headphone and speaker simultaneously. How it is possible?