# Android AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn stops working after sleep

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, headset, speaker

So I am trying to use some code found here on Stack Overflow in order to route audio from the Headset to the Speakers.

What I am currently doing is:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
sleep(15000);
```

What happens is that the audio is routed during the "sleep", however it gets back to the headset after the 15 seconds.
If I perform this without the sleep, the sound will go to the speaker and back to the headset very quickly.

After this call, my program dies. I would like that this would persist in the system, as the app [Headset Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bjemtj.headsettoggle&hl=en) does

Comment: Tried using `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` but got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not discover why my method wasn't working, but I found a workaround for it.

What I am doing at the moment is:

```
Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
// First 1 == FOR_MEDIA, second 1 == FORCE_SPEAKER. To go back to the default
// behavior, use FORCE_NONE (0).
setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);
```

Thanks to Michael from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210696/simultaneously-using-a-headphone-and-speaker).