# Set looping in ringtone in android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to play my currently set ringtone in android repeatedly 
Here is my code

```
Uri ring = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ring);
r.play();
```

But it plays only one time. How can i play it continuously until i stop my service?

Answer (score 0):

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(this);

Uri alarmRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alarmRingtoneUri);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start(); 
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (SecurityException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
is it possible to play sound on speaker even hands free is connected?

Comment: Look into this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12018786/3326331](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12018786/3326331)