# Is it possible to mute sound coming from the headphone and play the alarm on android on the external speaker?

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms, android-audiomanager, mute

It is possible to mute the headphone and play an alarm at the same time with one Audiomanager? I tried a couple of combinations of codes here but still has no luck. Here is my sample code.

```
AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 10, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
MediaPlayer thePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
thePlayer.start();
```

Can you explain what I'm missing with this code? Thank you!

To Give more detail on my main goal, I'm trying to develop an android app that logs temperature readings, the hardware that is being used for the reading is connected via the 3.5mm jack of any mobile phone, I requirement for this is to have a sound alarm when the temperature reach a certain value, now my problem is that, there is a static sound that the 3.5mm jack generates so if I force all sounds to the speakers, the static sound of the audio alarm would mix up with the sound alarm, so what I'm trying to is to still output the sound on the external speaker, but mute the once coming from the 3.5mm jack, the only problem that I'm getting is that, once you output the sounds to the speakers, it would all go to STREAM_MUSIC, and there is no way to pick the sounds the is originally coming from the 3.5 jack. Any suggestions regarding to this would be really really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12018786/2900127)? See if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.